# Get a href value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have multiple pop-ups on my site. On each popup hover there is a color selector. I get the selected by looking at the title of the image like this:

```
var kleur = jQuery(this).attr('title');
```

But now I want to reach the `a href` of the same div. I've tried the following code:

```
alert(jQuery('.photo').find('a').getAttribute("href"));
```

But I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

This is my HTML structure of each popup

```
<div class="popup" style="display: none;">
    <div class="product">           
        <div class="photo">
            <a href="" class="sendkleur" id="link69"> <!-- href im trying to reach -->     
                 <img id="product-collection-image-69" src="" alt="Test kleur" class="popup-image69"> 
            </a>
        </div>
        <a href="" class="sendkleur" id="link69">        
            <strong>Test kleur</strong>  
        </a>
        <span class="swatchLabel-category">Kleur:</span>
        <p class="float-clearer"></p>
        <div class="swatch-category-container" style="clear:both;" id="ul-attribute137-69">
             <img onclick="listSwitcher();" src="" id="a137-32" class="swatch-category" alt="Beige" width="12px" height="12px" title="Beige">
             <img onclick="listSwitcher();" src="" id="a137-36" class="swatch-category" alt="Zwart" width="12px" height="12px" title="Zwart">
        </div>
        <p class="float-clearer"></p>    
    </div>                   
</div>
```

Comment: Is `alert(jQuery('.photo').find('a').` a direct copy/paste from your code? If so, you've got a trailing dot and you aren't closing your alert parenthesis. Try editing your question to include a few more lines of context, and be sure that the exception is being thrown on that line.

Comment: @Seventoes I copied it wrong

Comment: Seems ok to me http://jsfiddle.net/9tx0jwfr/

Comment: Shouldn't you use `.attr("href")`? `getAttribute` is only available on DOM elements in pure Javascript, not on JQuery objects

Comment: @AlexK. K adding the [0] solved it

Comment: @user3164891 the reason it solved it is that [0] select the DOM element in pure JS through the Jquery object array. If you use `.attr("href")` you can use pure jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.getAttribute("href");` is available in JavaScript itself, but not in jQuery. Adding the `[0]` to it selects the DOM element and then running `getAttribute()` will select the DOM element related to your jQuery object, and then gets the attribute. However, using jQuerys `.attr()` allows you to select it directly in jQuery.

So both of these work:

```
// jQuery and pure JS
alert(jQuery('.photo').find('a')[0].getAttribute("href"));
// pure jQuery
alert(jQuery('.photo').find('a').attr("href"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
alert(jQuery('.photo').find('a').getAttribute("href"));
```

The above is incorrect. What you tried to do is using DOM function on jQuery object. To read `href` attribute on a jQuery object, use jQuery's `attr` function, like this:

```
alert(jQuery('.photo').find('a').attr("href"));
```

However, if you still wish to use `getAtrribute` which is not a jQuery's function, then do this:

```
alert(jQuery('.photo').find('a')[0].getAttribute("href"));
```

Didn't test this, but I don't see why it shouldn't work for you. Hope it helped. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing DOM and jQuery functions.

`getAttribute` is for plain DOM. You can get the plain element from a jQuery set by doing

```
alert(jQuery('.photo').find('a')[0].getAttribute("href"));
```

...Or, you could just use jQuery's method. ;)

```
alert(jQuery('.photo').find('a').attr("href"));
```